# Cognos: How to round an average of a data item result

Tags: reporting, average, rounding, cognos-8

I'm using Cognos Report Studio. I'm pretty new to the software. But anyway, I've created a query that is meant to count the number of days between two dates. There are multiple records and I need the average of all the days. I'm able to do all of this. But my result is 6.57254211... I want this number to be rounded. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I achieved the average by applying an aggregate function. I though the round would be applied the same way. But there is no Round in the rollup aggregate function option. I also tried to use _round() in my data item code, but that returned an error. Plus, I'm pretty sure that just rounds each individual number I get, not the average of all of them. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to round my average by creating a query calculation and doing _round([Weekdays]) for the code. [Weekdays] being the average I need rounded.